# Match a value from the table to a dropdown range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying this for a while now and am not able to figure out the `for` code for this problem.
I have a table in sheet1 with two columns, in one column I have positions, in the next I have people who can work on those positions.
In sheet2 I have the list of all the positions and the one that are supposed to be staffed are highlighted when you select a SKU, and two columns besides it is the dropdown list of the employees.
This same sheet also has a range which displays employee who are not working that day.
Tried to implement @BruceWayne answer the code is:

```
  Option Explicit
'use a constant to store the highlight color...
Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 9894500 'RGB(100, 250, 150)

Sub AssignBided()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cel1 As range
Dim cel2 As range
Dim line8 As range
Dim Offemp As range
Dim BidL8 As range
Dim BidL8E As range
Dim coresVal As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets("OT_Table")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Monday")
Set line8 = ws2.range("Line8_Hilight_Mon")
Set Offemp = ws2.range("Off_Mon")
Set BidL8 = ws1.range("BidedL8")
Set BidL8E = ws1.range("BidedL8_E")

For Each cel2 In BidL8E
    For Each cel1 In line8
        If IsHighlighted(cel1) Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Offemp, cel2.Value) > 0 Then
                coresVal = Evaluate("Index(" & BidL8E.Address & "),MATCH(" & cel1.Validation & "," & BidL8.Address & ",0))")
                Debug.Print coresVal
                cel1.Offset(0, 2).Value = coresVal
            End If
        End If
    Next cel1
Next cel2
End Sub

'Is a cell highlighted? EDIT: changed the function name to IsHighlighted
Function IsHighlighted(c As range)
    IsHighlighted = (c.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
End Function
```

This code is giving me this error: Object doesn't support this property or method. It highlights the `evaluate` line. Am I using this in some wrong manner?

Comment: Why is there an extra period in `If IsHighlighted(.L8) Then`? Also, what's the point of setting `L8` if you're going to use it as an iterable variable in your `For` loop?

Comment: @dwirony well I want to loop through every cell of the L8 range, if there is any other way of doing that I would be happy to implement that.
The extra period is a mistake on my part I will correct it.

Comment: Then that should be something like `For Each cell in L8` - also what is `BidL8`? You should put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and make sure all your variables are declared.

Comment: @dwirony BidL8 is the table in sheet1 as said in the question. The table has position against employee.

Comment: That may be what you think it is, but right now in your current code `BidL8` is nothing - you have to declare it and `Set` it to something.

Comment: @dwirony Sorry! error while typing the question. Now it would make much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I think this is what you are trying to do.
(I renamed some variables to make them a little easier to understand. Also, adjust the named ranges as needed. They may not all be on the "OT_Table" sheet, which I assumed they were. It wasn't clear.)

```
Sub AssignBided()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("OT_Table")
Dim cel As Range

Dim line8 As Range
Set line8 = ws.Range("Line8_Highlight_Mon")

Dim Offemp As Range
Set Offemp = ws.Range("Scheduled_Off")

Dim BidL8 As Range
Set BidL8 = ws.Range("BidedL8_T")

Dim coresVal As String
For Each cel In line8
    ' cel.Select
    If IsHighlighted(cel) Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Offemp, cel.Value) > 0 Then
            coresVal = Evaluate("INDEX(OFFSET(" & BidL8.Address & ",,2),MATCH(" & _
                cel.Value & "," & BidL8.Address & ",0))")
            Debug.Print coresVal
            cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = coresVal
        End If
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey I tried to implement the code but it is giving me the error: Object doesn't support this property or method. I have updated the question to show my corrected code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The Evaluate function